# overflow-y:hidden, but still scrollable with firefox on android

Tags: android, jquery, html, css, scroll

I open a partial view in an overlay using jquery (showing a fixed div and disable scrolling for the underlying webpage). This seems to work in chromium and firefox on the desktop, and also in chrome for android, but not in firefox/android:

```
$('a#manage-albums').click(function(){
    $.get( this.href )
        .done(function( data ) {
            $('div#flvr-overlay-content').html(data);
            $('div#flvr-overlay-back').show();
            $('html,body').css('overflow-y','hidden');
        });
    return false;
});
```

The overlay appears and shows its content, is fixed and everything looks good, but I can still scroll the underlying webpage..

I also have this meta tag in use, if that matters:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

How can I disable scrolling (overflow-y) also for firefox on android?

### edit:

It looks as if firefox does not like the `'overflow-y'`.

With this line:

```
$('html,body').css('overflow','hidden');`
```

the scrolling seems to be stopped  / reduced to the height of the firefox menu bar.

Comment: it is a HTML/PHP/JQuery website. I don't know what a webview is.

Comment: I fought against this problem yesterday and gave up eventually and removed my modals from mobile. But some have said that adding `position: fixed` to body and/or html could work. I didn't test it, though.

Comment: I have tried `$('html,body').css('overflow-y','hidden').css('position','fixed');` Nothing changed

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe adding overflow: hidden !important to all elements with * selector could work, and then add overflow: auto !important to your album element. Not a pretty solution, but may work.

Comment: @haheute well did you get it to work? an accept/upvote or both would be nice!

Comment: not really. I did something different and used `overflow` instead of `overflow-y`. perhaps it is a firefox bug, I don't know

Answer (score 0):

there are a number of ways to do it, first try

```
gridview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

});
```

thats for a gridview.

[Source](https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2012/05/01/disable-vertical-scrolling-of-gridview/)

for a scrollview use "verticalScrollDisabled = true"

or use (javascript)

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
```

or [jquery](http://workfunc.com/how-to-disable-scrolling-on-mobile/)

```
$(document).bind('touchmove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

failing that use `$("body").css("overflow", "hidden!important");` and that should work

Comment: I have tried `$('html,body').attr('style', 'overflow-y: hidden !important');` . That did not help. What I don't understand is, why chrome does it, and firefox on my PC does it as well. Only firefox/android still scrolls. Something must be different there..

Comment: Not yet. I don't know where and what·and think it should work using jquery and css.

Comment: added a jquery answer

Comment: you're too fast ;) I would also like to understand why it is not working in firefox/android

Comment: you should visit caniuse.com some things are not compatible with all browsers. Firefox has serious issues!